# What is the equivalent of doing a plain `git reset <sha>` in magit?

Tags: magit, git

I sometimes want to undo a commit without losing the changes, but just placing them back into an uncommitted and unstaged state. To do that at the cli, I do just `git reset <sha-of-previous-commit>`.

How would I do the same in magit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>X s</kbd> to do so.

Using the <kbd>X</kbd> prefix has the benefit that it shows you all the available `git reset` variants.

This is also documented in the [Resetting](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Resetting.html) section of the manual.